# Converting an IEnumerable of objects to IEnumerable of Tuples

Tags: c#, lambda

I have an `IEnumerable` of objects of the following class:

```
class MyTuple 
{
    public string Left;
    public string Right;
}
```

as `myTuples`

Is there any way, by lambda exp  by which I could convert this into `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>` without a for each loop?

Comment: Why do you need to convert your class into a  `Tuple<string,string>` at all?

Comment: read more about tuples : http://pranayamr.blogspot.no/2012/12/tuple-type-in-c40.html

Comment: The object is the result of an API. I need to format the result and print it to a file.

Answer (score 6):

```
var newList = myTuples.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.Left, x.Right));
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know about Create method, because I do not use tuples :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = myTuples.Select(t => new Tuple<string, string>(t.Left, t.Rigth));
```

Note: I would suggest you to use class with more informative name and properties than Tuple or custom tuple.